# LXDE Chromium help

Tags: chromium, lxde

Under xfce, I managed to specify which user Chromium should start up with when an icon on the panel was clicked.

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/home/myaccountname/.config/chromium/Profile 2

My question is, how can I make something like this in LXDE? I cannot specify icons nor can I set up a command to run at start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken LXDE uses openbox, and so your "autostart" script should be in "/home/usernamerhere/.config/openbox/autostart.sh".

And BTW if you don't know, you do have to put a "&" at the end of each process or it will wait until that process ends to start the next...
For example my autostart.sh is:

```
conky &
tint2 &
gnome-settings-daemon &
volumeicon &
feh --bg-scale /home/scrivener/Pictures/a64background.png &
xcompmgr -cfF -t-9 -l-11 -r9 -o.95 -D6 &
guake --sync /etc/x11/Germinal &
```

Which starts conky, tint2, gnome-settings-daemon, and volume icon under default settings, and xcompmgr, guake, and feh under my custom options...

Hope it helps, but if LXDE doesn't use openbox then I just wasted my time NOT helping you...